# Supose that $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow R$ are R-Integrable, $f \leq h \leq g$ and $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b g$. It is true that $h$ is R-Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

If we don't have the supose that $\int_a^b f = \int_a^b g$ it is false, but i don't know verify if in this case this affirmation is true.

I know that: there step functions $\varphi_f, \varphi_g, \psi_f, \psi_g$, defined by one partition $P$,  such that $\varphi_f \leq f \leq \psi_f$ and $\varphi_g \leq g \leq \psi_g$ so that $\int_{a}^{b}{(\psi_f-\varphi_f)}< \varepsilon$ and $\int_{a}^{b}{(\psi_g-\varphi_g)}< \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$. How can this help me? This is the right way to start thinking about this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all there!

Put $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g=:I$. Then $\int_a^b \phi_f\leq I\leq \int_a^b\psi_f\>$, and similarly for $g$. It follows that
$$\left|\int_a^b \phi_f-I\right|<\epsilon, \qquad\left|\int_a^b\psi_g -I\right|<\epsilon$$
and therefore
$$\int_a^b (\psi_g-\phi_f)<2\epsilon\ .$$
So we have a partition $P$ and associated step functions $\phi_f$, $\psi_g$ with $\phi_f\leq h\leq\psi_g\>$, and
$$\int_a^b (\psi_g-\phi_f)<2\epsilon\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start. Hint for the next step: $\varphi_f\le h\le \psi_g$.

Hint the second: Don't forget to use that $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$, and note that $\int_a^b \varphi_f\approx\int_a^b f$, while $\int_a^b \psi_g\approx\int_a^b g$. (For a rigorous proof, you need to replace the $\approx$ with proper estimates involving $\varepsilon$, of course.)

Comment: Ah, I am beginning to see where you get stuck. I added a second hint.